# Link back to question in moderator "Show deleted comments" page is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

On the moderator "Show *n* deleted comments" page for a question there's a link that is supposed to take you back to the original post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/12632536/comments

[image]

Instead of linking back to the question it seems to link to somewhere that doesn't exist:

> https://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/12632536/link

[image]

Comment: Is that something like incatnito mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Link replacement just went wonky there, my bad.